# Uniqueness of JNF

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have to prove the uniqueness of Jordan normal form (up to permutation of Jordanblocks).
Of corse there are a lot of hardscrabble methods (for example proving the invariance of the 
lengths of sequences of choosen basis vectors associated to a JNF or similary) but my 
prof told me that there is a more elegant method by using a commutative diagram.
So I would like to construct my proof in this way.

My idea: Let $V$ complex vector space, $\phi$ an endomorphism and 
$V_{\lambda_i} ^{j} = Ker((\lambda_i Id -\phi)^k_{j,\lambda_i}$  one of $s(\lambda_i) $ invariant subspaces under $\phi$.
I know that $V = \bigoplus _i {\oplus _{j=1} ^{s(\lambda_i)} V_{\lambda_i} ^{j}}$. My intention is to construct
the comm diagramm in following way: 
Let $J_{k_{j,\lambda_i}}$ the Jordan matrix of size $k_{j,\lambda_i}$ corresponding to the restriction of $\phi$ to the 
invariant subspace $V_{\lambda_i} ^{j}$. Is it enough for the uniqueness of JNF to show that following diagram
commutates? If yes, why?

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V \cong \bigoplus _i {\oplus _{j=1} ^{s(\lambda_i)} V_{\lambda_i} ^{j}} @>{\phi}  >> \bigoplus _i {\oplus _{j=1} ^{s(\lambda_i)} V_{\lambda_i} ^{j}} \\
@VVpr_{\lambda_i,j}V  @VVpr_{\lambda_i,j}V  \\
V_{\lambda_i} ^{j} @>{J_{k_{j,\lambda_i}}}>> V_{\lambda_i} ^{j}
\end{CD}
$$

???
my incredulity is based on seemingly arbitrary choice of the basis...